# Pass parameters to popup window from button - MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, button, razor

I have a button in my view that creates a pop-up window but I am not sure how to pass parameters back to the controller which will be running in the pop-up window.
I have looked at many methods of new pop-up windows but I need to be able to change the size of the window so I dont think target="_blank" will work.

Below is the code I am using to open the new window, can someone please suggest how to pass parameters to the uploadFeedback controller please.

```html
<input type="button" id="btnpopu" value="Upload" onclick="ShowPopup();" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    ShowPopup = function () {
        window.open('/ViewAssignment/UploadFeedback', "PopupWindow", 'width=400px,height=400px,top=150,left=250');
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: you're bypassing the controller with the window.open().  have you considered passing control to the controller from the button, and then create a view for the "popup" that the controller calls?  or, use a modal on your current page so you're not referring to a new window / view.

Comment: by modal do you mean something like a partial view? i'm quite new to mvc

Comment: A modal is a popup.  It's not a separate view.  See here for an example:  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: You can pass parameters using query string. `window.open('/ViewAssignment/UploadFeedback?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value', "PopupWindow", 'width=400px,height=400px,top=150,left=250');` [Read this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)